# Java: implementing a list

Tags: java

So I'm learning Java and I want to implement a singly-linked list, but when I try to print it, it goes into an infinite loop, printing only the first element, as if the `temp` doesn't get reassigned. What's wrong here?

```
public class Cons
{
public int stuff;
public Cons next;

public Cons(int i)
{
  this(i, null);
}

public void show()
{
  Cons temp = this; 
  while(temp != null)
  {
    System.out.println(temp.stuff);
    temp = temp.next;
  }
}

public void push(int i)
{
  stuff = i;
  next = this;
}

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Cons head = new Cons(2);
    head.push(3);
    head.push(12);
    head.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't compile because of `this(i, null);` in the constructor.

Comment: You're not actually adding elements/nodes to your "list", you're just overwriting the previous one each time.

Answer (score 3):

In this block:

```
public void push(int i)
{
  stuff = i;
  next = this;
}
```

You are assigning the node's `next` to itself.

Try this instead:

```
public void push(int i)
{
  next = new Cons(i);
}
```

That will remove the self-loop, but then you will still have the problem of remembering where the tail is.  I will leave that as an exercise, since this is homework.

Another problem, pointed out in a comment, is that your code shouldn't compile as is, because you are attempting to call a constructor that doesn't exist.

If you want to call `this(i, null)` you need a constructor that takes `(int, Cons)` as its arugments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create code as shown [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations). You need Container to hold nodes, and Node to represent single node in list

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
next = this
```

is wrong, you should instead create a new entry

```
next = new Cons(stuff);
stuff = i;
```

otherwise the next entry will point to the current one!
Note that the order of the elements is reversed if you do it that way..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void push(int i)
{
  stuff = i;
  next = this; //here's the problem.
}
```

You need something like:

```
public void push(int i)
{
  Cons newnext = new Cons(i)
  tail.next = newnext;
  tail = newnext;
}
```

and of course you need a reference to the tail of your linked list *somewhere*.